# How to check the number of active cursors in django

Tags: python, django, cursor

I am creating a django cursor in a views.py

```
def getDetails(request, name):
    sql = 'select * from myTable where name=%s' % name
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

I don't explicitly close the cursor or use context manager (with keyword).
I want to know if the cursors are destroyed or they persist after each request response cycle in django. I am using django 1.4

Comment: Why are you doing this, rather than using the model layer?

Comment: I cannot query the database that way. The database is not mine and I have limited permissions